# To get the specific properties from list

Tags: c#, list

My list contents are as follows,

```
List<MyData> DICT_list = new List<MyData>()
{
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Alpha", Dimension="Length", Classes=null},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Alpha", Dimension="Length", Classes="Process"},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Alpha", Dimension="breath", Classes="Activity"},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Alpha", Dimension="Height", Classes="Workflow"},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Beta", Dimension="Height", Classes=null},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Beta", Dimension="Height", Classes="Workflow"},
   new MyData{ Dictionay="Beta", Dimension="Length", Classes="Workflow"}
};
```

I want to have the data for eg as below,

```
 Want to get All the Classes of Dimension=length in dictionary=ALPHA only...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---------Updation in question-------

```
public struct MyData
        {
            public string Dictionary { get; set; }
            public string Dimension { get; set; }
            public string Classes { get; set; }
        }
```

and executing as below,

```
var SelectedValue = DICT_list.Where(d => d.Dimension == "Length" && d.Dictionary == "Alpha").Select(d => d.Class);
                foreach (var value in SelectedValue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
                }
```

I am getting following error at line `MessageBox.show(value.ToString);` as

`Object Reference not set to instance of an object`

And I my list contains the desired element, I have tested it by following command,

```
string count = DICT_list.Count.ToString(); // Here count gives the value 14 which has the desired Dictionary and DImension name along with several classes which I need to fetch..
```

-------------------Updated question---------

I guess I know why this error(if I am not wrong) is coming because My first value for classes for new dimension is null in List, I am sorry for wrong question, got to know now by testing, **can I do something which will ignore the null value and move for next from list..**

Comment: Try rewording your question. I can't understand this monster sentence.

Comment: It looks like a riddle! Rephrase your question!

Comment: Does `DICT_list.Select(dl=>dl.Classes)` help?

Comment: @DominicKexel..sorry for confusion, I have explained my question, hope U understand it now..

Comment: Using LINQ expression could help you.

Comment: @Muctadir ..I have tried by doing the way u suggested, I am getting classed of both the dictionary alpha and beta..bt I want classes of only one dictionary only...and if condition prevails then of the specific dimension as well

Comment: @Reshma what type `Dictionay` property has? What is `Aplha` and `Beta`?

Comment: Explain your question with simple sentence..

Comment: @Ammar..U still can't get my question which I assume is the simplest way I can explain it as I have did it currently..

Comment: @Reshma is there some problems with my solution?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy.. I totally appreciate your efforts, thanks a lott, will gave try and will let u know..

Comment: That question is much clearer now, Reshma. :)

Comment: It would also be helpful if you provide MyData Class

Comment: Please visit updated question

Comment: Hey frnds..thanks for the support..I got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - simply filter list by `Dimension` *and* `Dictionay`. Second - project each item from result by selecting `Classes` only. That will give you `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
var query = DICT_list.Where(d => d.Dimension == "Length" && d.Dictionay == "Aplha")
                     .Select(d => d.Classes);
```

Or query syntax:

```
var query = from d in DICT_list
            where d.Dimension == "Length" && d.Dictionay == "Aplha"
            select d.Classes;
```

I suggest you to take look on [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: Do that Dictionay == "Aplha" in first query need to be d.Dictionary=="Aplha".. anywayz..dis is not helping me, still it s giving me data of both the dictionary and all the dimensions,

Comment: @Reshma sorry, you are right, it should be `d.Dictionay`. And it's impossible what you say - this query includes filter by dimension, so you can't get all dimensions

Comment: Hey.. I have updated my question, can you please look at error occurring at guide me through it..

Comment: @Reshma you are selecting `d.Class` instead of `d.Classes`. Even if this is just a typo, you are selecting string which can be `null`. Then when you call `value.ToString()` you have `NullReferenceException`. Solution - thus string is already string, you don't need to call `ToString()`. Just show `value`.

Comment: ...thanks a lott, I made it working by skiping null value and to check other value but your solution, I was unaware of the error, thanks for explanation, I know even though its basic and I am very late at knowing it but I am very happy to learn it..thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

The Solution given by @Sergey Berezovskiy works properly.
here is a proof for that.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<MyData> DICT_list = new List<MyData>()
        {
           new MyData{ Dictionay="Aplha", Dimension="Length", Classes="Process"},
           new MyData{ Dictionay="Aplha", Dimension="breath", Classes="Activity"},
           new MyData{ Dictionay="Aplha", Dimension="Height", Classes="Workflow"},
           new MyData{ Dictionay="Beta", Dimension="Height", Classes="Workflow"},
           new MyData{ Dictionay="Beta", Dimension="Length", Classes="Workflow"}
        };

        var query = DICT_list.Where(d => d.Dimension == "Length" && d.Dictionay == "Aplha")
                 .Select(d => d.Classes);

        foreach (var VARIABLE in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.ToString());
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT : Process**

Extented answer for your later question : **"can I do something which will ignore the null value and move for next from list.."**

This query might help you:

```
var query = DICT_list.Where(d => d.Dimension == "Length" && d.Dictionay == 
"Aplha" && d.Classes != null).Select(d => d.Classes);
```

Comment: Hey.. I have updated my question, can you please look at error occurring at guide me through it..

Comment: Oh Hi...I guess I know why dis error is coming because My first value for classes is null in List, I am sorry for wrong explanation, got to know now by testing, can I do something which will ignore the null value and move for next from list..